# Azure B2C custom claim is not saved in custom Edit profile policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've set up custom edit profile policy. This is my `SelfAsserted-ProfileUpdate`:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-ProfileUpdate">
          <DisplayName>User ID signup</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.profileupdate</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />

            <!-- Optional claims. These claims are collected from the user and can be modified. Any claim added here should be updated in the
                 ValidationTechnicalProfile referenced below so it can be written to directory after being updated by the user, i.e. AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId. -->
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Phone" />

          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Required claims -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />

            <!-- Optional claims. These claims are collected from the user and can be modified. Any claim added here should be updated in the
                 ValidationTechnicalProfile referenced below so it can be written to directory after being updated by the user, i.e. AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId. -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Phone" />

          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

There is the custom claim `extension_Phone`. I can see it in the edit UI:
[image]

But when I try to change it, it's not saved. On the other hand `givenName` and `surname` are saved correctly. I do not see any error in logs. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, i was inattentive. It says I need to add claim to `AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId`:

```
Optional claims. These claims are collected from the user and can be modified. Any claim added here should be updated in the
                 ValidationTechnicalProfile referenced below so it can be written to directory after being updated by the user, i.e. AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId.
```

So, I added to `AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId`, like this and it worked:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">false</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <PersistedClaims>
            <!-- Required claims -->
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />

            <!-- Optional claims -->
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_Phone" /> <--- HERE
          </PersistedClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It saves me a lot of time.  My problem for attribute "displayName" is also not to add it in "PersistedClaim".